# Cannot extract the OBJ of 3D view

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I have a Revit file with two different 3D views which I can see them in Autodesk viewer ;however, when I extract model manifest, there is only one OBJ file and I can extract only one.

How can I extract the OBJ of all the 3D views that are created in the model?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to translate your file into `OBJ` first using the **ModelDerivative** API.

According to [Supported Translations](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/), `Revit` files doesn't support `OBJ` derivatives, so can't translate the whole file into `OBJ`.

But you can extract the geometry, take a look at this tutorial : [Extract Geometry](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/xtract-geometry-from-source-file/task5-extract_geometry/) in the official Autodesk Forge documentation.
In the translate payload you need to pass the model guid of the 3D view you want to translate, so you should be able to translate all your 3D views.